# Exporting functions with React TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

### ***The Setup***

I have a sidebar component that opens and closes when the user clicks a button...

```
/*  Sidebar.tsx  */
export function PersistentDrawerLeft(){
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false)
  const [sidebarText, setSidebarText] = React.useState('')

  const handleDrawerOpen = (sidebarText) => {
    setSidebarText(sidebarText)
    setOpen(true)
  }
  
  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false)
    setSidebarText('')
  }
}
```

I would like to export the `handleDrawerOpen/Close` functions so that other components can control the sidebar, and tell the sidebar what to display.

### ***Where it will be used***

Namely, when a user clicks in an input, the sidebar opens with comments about the field. Something like this:

```
/*  MyForm.tsx. */
<TextField
  id="make" 
  label="Make"
  data-sidebarText="The make of the car, ie: Ford, Chevy, etc." 
  onClick={handleDrawerOpen(this.data-sidebarText)}
  onFocusOut={handleDrawerClose()}
  value={make}
/>
```

### ***The Problem***

The problem is the linter doesn't like my `export` decorator. As seen above, it says `Modifiers cannot appear here` (inside the function I assume).

When I try to move these outside of the function that error goes away, but then it has a problem with `useState`. It says `React.useState` cannot be called at the top level...`

Comment: You don't export functions from components (they're effectively internal to them). If you need to control the state from other component you pass a `prop` to your component and it sets its internal state instead. Or as an alternative, provide a callback to props of other components for them to notify you.

Comment: The Dom is a tree and it is not possible make those functions available to parent elements. In this case you could use react context or implement a custom hook, but it doesn't work with functional component.

Comment: State flows _down_ to the leaves of the tree, never up towards the trunk. If `PersistentDrawerLeft` can be opened or closed by other elements on the screen, then it should _not_ own the state about whether it's opened or closed. In this case that state needs to move up until it's at the level shared by the controls for that state, and what the state controls.

Comment: So should just open be defined in a parent file, or open and the two functions?